# How to install Evolution 3.6.2 from 13.04 into 12.10?

Tags: evolution, backport

It's all in the question, really.  Currently running Evolution 3.6.0 on Ubuntu 12.10 and, as anybody who has tried this at all will know, it locks up regularly with a 'saving user interface' report and several 'unknown background task' reports.  The only way to exit under these circumstances is to kill Evolution cold.  This is making Evolution almost unusable.

Is it possible to back-port manually from raring to quantal or is there somewhere to request that it should be done at distro level through the proper Ubuntu channels?

EDIT ===========================================================

I was able to make Evolution much more usable, and stop all the 'Saving user interface' lockups by unchecking the option to show sender's photo from address book, i.e. edit > preferences > mail preferences > headers > sender's photograph.

Can't remember where I got this from, but believe it was from one of the developers.  Hope it helps those still struggling with this.

Comment: Successfully upgraded.  However, same problems recurring...  An altogether different issue, I know.

Comment: Evolution 3.6.2 is now in the Ubuntu 12.10 repositories: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/e/evolution/evolution_3.6.2-0ubuntu0.1/changelog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the same reasons I've backported Evolution 3.6.2 from raring to Ubuntu 12.10. You can download my packages from

- https://support.bec.at/download/evolution_3.6.2-ubuntu1210.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. One or two problems encountered.  Most fundamental is that I'm on 64 bit so probably need the AMD64 version of those libraries.  Having inadvertantly tried to install the .debs in your tarball, I had dependency issues reported on the gir1.2 installation - dependencies on gir-freedesktop for instance.  Is there anywhere else I should be looking?  TIA

Comment: gir* is probably not necessary. Remove the gir-packages and fix dependency with "apt-get install -f".

Comment: Sorry I don't have a 64-bit installation yet, you can try to build it yourself, short HOWTO
- http://www.mail-archive.com/evolution-list@gnome.org/msg20699.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, which has proved successful.  For anybody else taking this route here is what I had to do.  I downloaded and built the *.debs as instructed in  Josef's message.  I then tried to follow the install instructions in The tarball listed above, but got an error.  I then settled for a _sudo dpkg -i *.deb_ which installed everything beautifully.

Answer (score 4):

I've now created a PPA for Evolution. So you can use the latest stable release (currently 3.6.4) on Ubuntu 12.10.

To add/install it, simple open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:support-bec/evolution
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

No warranty for anything, this just works for me.